# Tableau Gauge chart with Needle - Red Amber Green

Tags: tableau-api

I need to create the 2 Gauge chart with the below mentioned criteria.

But not able to do it properly for my requirement. How can I create a Gauge chart for the below threshold in my Tableau workbook?

I need to create the 2 separate Gauge chart with the Below criteria

1 Chart

```
<=2% - GREEN

>2 - AMBER

>5 - RED
```

2nd Chart

```
>=99% - GREEN

<99% - AMBER

<97.5 - RED
```

Here is the formula I have got from Tableau site. But I do not know how to incorporate my requirements inside this calculation.

```
A

IF [Value]<.5 THEN [Value] 

ELSE .5

END


B

IF [Value]<.5 THEN .5-[Value] END


C

IF [Value]>.5

THEN [Value]-.5

END


D

IF [Value]>.5 THEN 1-[Value]

ELSE .5

END


E

MIN(1)


Needle1

IF [Value]<=.5 THEN .005 END


Needle2

IF [Value]>.5 THEN .005 END


Dummy

'Dummy'
```

For 2nd chart below is the output. =99% - GREEN , <99% - AMBER , <97.5 - RED

[image]

For the 1st chart: <=2% - GREEN , 2 - AMBER , 5 - RED

[image]

Comment: What specific problem are you having with implementing this?

Comment: Hi, Please check my above chart. For the1st chart if it is <=2% it should be red. In my Chart now pointer is showing in the Red color but If it is less then <=2% it should be green color but above query will not work I believe.      For the 2nd chart if it is more than 99% it should be green and the pointer also showing in the green color but green is visible very lighter.

Comment: a better idea would be to not use semicircular gauge charts at all: they are a dataviz abomination. Bullet charts are easier to do, more compact and visually far better.